# Javascript Short Circuit is not returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a js variable that is being generated through php on a php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var shadeData = <?php echo $formattedShadeData; ?>;
</script>
```

This variable will only be defined on one page, so I want to prevent other pages from throwing an error when they load. In one of my javascript files, I want to stop the code from running if the variable has not yet been defined so I've been trying:

```
var shadeData = shadeData || null;

if(!shadeData){ return false; }
```

However, this isn't working and I'm still getting shadeData is not defined. There are a couple of functions in the code below these lines that use the variable but ideally, this wouldn't run when the second line returns false.

Comment: Set `shadeData` to `null` or `false` in your PHP script. JavaScript is weird with undefined values.

Comment: At first: don't use multiple `var` declarations for the same variable. Second: If you call out some variable input via php, just wrap a `json_encode($formattedShadeData)` around the php variable. This prevents syntax errors if `$formattedShadeData` is empty.

Comment: @ww139 thanks, I'll try this if nothing else works. My instinct is to put it in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `return` in the global / top-level scope of a JavaScript program.

Your idea should work fine after a minor tweak: wrap all of your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```
// If shadeData is already defined and falsey, this is unnecessary. But included for clarity.
var shadeData = shadeData || null;

(function () {
    if (!shadeData) {
        return;
    }
    // From now on within this function, shadeData is truthy.
}());

// shadeData is not necessarily truthy down here.
console.log('shadeData:', shadeData);
```

In the real world this would usually be accomplished with a main entry function (often named `init`) that is called conditionally.

```
function init() {
    // I am only run when shadeData is truthy.
}
if (shadeData) {
    init();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying the second option but am still getting shadeData is not defined

Comment: This is being thrown by the if (shadeData) line. It seems like the if statement doesn't terminate the code

Comment: Only `return` is capable of "stopping" the code from continuing. But obviously `if`/`else` constructs can guarantee the conditions under which certain code runs. Perhaps you need an `else {}` around your code that is throwing? `if (shadeData) {} else { codeThatIsThrowing(); }`

Comment: Thanks–ended up going with
`if (typeof shadeData !== 'undefined') {
     init();
 }`